# How can I link docker containers in mesos cluster (dc/os) running on Azure?

Tags: azure, docker, hyperlink, containers, dcos

I am setting up a multi container application on mesos cluster on Azure using azure container service and currently stuck in linking containers.

My setup brief info:
- Mesos cluster is deployed on Azure using Azure container service
- It's a 3 container application - A, B and C
- B is dependent on A and C is dependent on A & B- 
- A is deployed currently

How can I link the above containers?

Thanks,
Suraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by linking you mean Docker's `--link` then [thats deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) practice and inter-container communication should be done using Docker networks and port mappings.

For DC/OS - you have some different ways to achieve this (also called Service Discovery). I have written a blog post explaining these different tools by examples: http://blog.itaysk.com/2017/04/28/dcos-service-discovery-and-load-balancing-by-example

If you don't want to read through that long post and looking for a recommendation: Try using VIPs.

When creating the application (either from Marathon or DC/OS UI), look for the 'VIP' setting. Enter an IP there (it can be a made up IP) and port. Your service will be discoverable under this IP:Port.

More on VIPs: https://dcos.io/docs/1.9/networking/load-balancing-vips/virtual-ip-addresses/

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for !! Thanks a ton Itay!! Gone through your article (line by line). An excellent article to understand container communication :)

Comment: I'm happy to hear that :)